# Can Global.asax file be ignored if I don't use ASP.NET compatibility for a WCF Service?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, iis-7.5, global-asax

Does the setting of ASP.NET compatibility Mode have any impact on the events fired on Global.asax file of the WCF service?

Moreover, if ASP.NET compatibility is FALSE, is it possible that Global.asax is completely ignored and none of the events within would be fired?

**P.S**: I am trying to figure out why my Global.asax file is not hit when I deploy my service to a different environment.)

Answer (score 1):

For HTTP access to the service, if ASP.NET compatibility is enabled, then the Global.asax events are fired; if it's disabled then the service doesn't get the ASP.NET lifecycle model, and even with it enabled it won't matter if accessing through, say, TCP.

Comment: Then what I do not understand is, when I hit F5 in Visual Studio to start debugging, on my local machine I see that ServiceHostingEnvironment.AspNetCompatibilityEnabled = False. However, Global.asax still fires the event. (Is there a special case when you debug a WCF Service? )

Comment: @pencilCake Hm, this _could_ be a Visual Studio environment quirk. Have you set the thing up in IIS locally, or elsewhere, and see the behaviour?

Comment: btw, <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/> did not make a change on my Test environment. (In my logs, I write its value which is set to TRUE) but Global.asax still not hit. :(